# How to adjust KeyRepeat and RepeatDelay in OSX Sierra?

Tags: macos, macos-sierra

In El Capitan I used Seil and Karabiner for keystroke/repeat/delay finetuning. The Seil/Karabiner combination is no longer working in OSX 10.12 (Sierra). How can I adjust my KeyRepeat and RepeatDelay settings?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since Seil stopped working in OSX Sierra - [Karabiner Elements](https://github.com/tekezo/Karabiner-Elements) now inherits some of its functionality - KeyRepeat and delay (InitialKeyRepeat) can't be adjusted to sane values anymore.

After reading issues on github for a while a working solution emerged. The settings involved are:

```
defaults write -g KeyRepeat -int 1
defaults write -g InitialKeyRepeat -float 8.5
```

Those settings work good for me. If you want to play around, be sure to reboot to let the new values take effect. Some were saying logout/login is enough, but it wasn't for me.

Also worth noting: In `System Preferences -> Accessibility` be sure to uncheck the Press & Hold Settings for keyboard. It interferes with the KeyRepeat Setting.

Unrelated note: I had to install Karabiner Elements for simultaneous usage of two keyboards. Sierra reconfigured them so I couldn't use option/alt/shift/command cross keyboard. With Karabiner Elements it is again possible to press shift on the left keyboard and e.g. `A` on the right keyboard to write a capital A.